# Linux Docker and the underlying caching, nscd, hosts

Tags: linux, apache, docker, hosts

if i place httpd in a docker container, should also start the nscd inside the container and configure the /etc/hosts, etc. or should i leave it to the underlying OS to do the caching and name resolve ? whats the best practice here ?

Thanks !!

Comment: Could you give a brief description for the problem you are trying to solve?

Comment: well lets say i start something in a container, be it simple wordpress or tor proxy or something bigger like weblogic doesnt really matter. if i want to i can also start nscd service inside the container and i can configure my /etc/hosts also inside a container. what i dont understand is how does the web app inside the container reaches the cache, can it work with nscd on the host OS or is it better (performance) to run it in a container or maybe it has to be inside container and theres no way around it. im talking about somewhat bigger environment with a large DNS infrastructure.

Comment: Ok, I have never used nscd before, but I did some quick research. It looks like you connect to it over a socket, if so I would run it in it's own container then bind mount the socket with other containers so they can connect to it. This allows you to run it just once and have many containers connect to it. If you added it to each container then you would have many copies of the same process, and not very efficient

Answer (score 0):

The application running in the container will use the containers configuration to resolve DNS requests. This is dependent upon which source container you are running.

If you need the container to have non default behaviour (say use a specific DNS server for resolution) then it is best to roll your own version of the container with modified DNS configuration.